# Theorems and parskip

Tags: spacing, parskip

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{parskip}    % paragraph spacing: without this command there is spacing between the paragraph and the proposition

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
This is some text

This is some other text in another paragraph

\begin{proposition}
This is the proposition
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

If I comment the line

```
\usepackage{parskip}
```

then the spacing between `This is some other text in another paragraph` and the Proposition looks fine. Instead, for some reason that I don't understand, when I use `parskip`, the spacing before the Propositions disappears.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following after loading amsthm and parskip packages:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\patchcmd\deferred@thm@head
  {\addvspace{-\parskip}}
  {}
  {}{\typeout{\string\deferred@thm@head patch failed!}}

\makeatletter
```

The problem is that the parskip package reduces the spaces around lists (and theorems are lists) to zero (because of a positive `\parskip` coming on top) but amsthm explicitly removes the `\parskip`  so you end up with 0.

#### Edit

Added the detection and correction into the `parskip` package, so it will show up on the next CTAN release.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!! :)